# select master page at run time for a specific page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-web-developer

I have an asp page employeeHome.aspx and I have two master pages adminMasterPage.master for Admin login and userMasterPage.master for normal user login as I have 2 types of user login one as Admin and other normal user. And I want to set adminMasterPage.master as a master page for employeeHome.aspx in case of normal user login (just for this page).
How can I do this?

Comment: I have to show adminMasterPage as master page of the page employeeHome.aspx for the normal user login. but I am not getting how I can do that.

Comment: Have you used any session variables?

Comment: yes I have session "empCode" which will give me either it is a admin or normal user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code to change the master page in `Page_PreInit` event.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "MasterPage.master";
}
```

Comment: Where do I call this Page_PreInit method? Is anywhere in the employeeHome.aspx's page_Load()?

Comment: it's a separate page method. It's a part of asp.net page life cycle.

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) for more detail about page life cycle

Comment: I am getting the error- The file '/Employee/AdminMaster.Master' does not exist. AdminMaster page is here StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.master in my code so I tried this.MasterPageFile = "/~StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.Master"; but giving same error- The file '/~StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.Master' does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code at `employeeHome.aspx` page

```
 protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["empCode"] != null)
            {
                if (Session["empCode"].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    this.MasterPageFile = Server.MapPath("adminMasterPage.master");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: check the answer again, the condition was having "!=" comparison.. now I did update it :).

Comment: what value you have in "Session["empCode"]" for normal user?

Comment: if (Session["IsEmporAdm"].ToString() == "0")
{//admin login}
else{//normal user} Its entering the right condition and not giving any error but this.MasterPageFile = "adminMasterPage.master"; is not having any effect after executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that by having the required master page file specified in the PreInit event, which is a part of the page life cycle..

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "adminMasterPage.master";  //For Admin

    //this.MasterPageFile = "userMasterPage.master";  - For Normal User
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error- The file '/Employee/AdminMaster.Master' does not exist. AdminMaster page is here StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.master in my code so I tried this.MasterPageFile = "~StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.Master"; but giving same error- The file '/Employee/~StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.Master' does not exist.

Comment: how can I give the path of my page to this.MasterPageFile?

Comment: Make that to: this.MasterPageFile = "/StyleLibrary/layout/AdminMaster.Master";

Answer (score 0):

This worked this way and here what I did as suggest by @Iswanto San and made changes in the path.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IsEmporAdm"].ToString() == "0")
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/StyleLibrary\\layout\\AdminMaster.Master";
        }
        else
        {
            this.MasterPageFile = "~/StyleLibrary\\layout\\UserMaster.Master";
        }
    }
```